# jQuery Mobile Problems with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I really need to create a collapsible set list and I've found that the jquery Mobile is great. But when I put their template inside a page on Wordpress it messes up the entire page.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn4Br.png

You can hardly see the navbar and the other page elements and everything is all scattered. I think it has something to do with the http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css and the wordpress's css.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could make this work?  Thanks for your time and expertise!

Code I'm using:
demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html

Comment: probably the css of jquery is overruling your wordpress css...

Comment: did you just put the link references in the `<head>` section of your header.php?